# Android Marshmallow FileUtils.copyFile() creating 0.00 B Size files at Given location while on Lollipop its working fine

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, file-copying, apache-commons-io

I am copying image file to desired location on internal storage with method

```
FileUtils.copyFile(File srcFile, File destFile, boolean preserveFileDate)
```

under package `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils`.

It is working fine on Lollipop OS and copy the file smoothly but on Marshmallow OS it not working and creating 0.00 B size file.

Device: Lenovo A7000 Lollipop Upgraded with Marshmallow 6.0.

```
FileManager.copyFile(fileName, cameraUtil.getPath(), "abc"))

public static synchronized boolean copyFile(String fileName, String fromPath, String status){
    File fromFile = new File(fromPath);
    String toPath = createToPath(status);
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(toPath)) {
        if(fileName.contains(" ")){
            fileName.replace(" ","_");
        }
        File toFile = new File(toPath+"/"+fileName);
        try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(fromFile, toFile);
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

public static String createToPath(String status){
    File aFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), FileConstants.ROOT_FOLDERNAME+"/"status);
    if(performMkDir(aFile)){
        return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+FileConstants.ROOT_FOLDERNAME+"/"+status;
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}

private static boolean performMkDir(File file){
    if(!file.exists()){
        if(!file.mkdirs()){
            Log.e(TAG, "could not create root folder.");
            return false;
        } else{
            Log.i(TAG, "created root folder.");
            return true;
        }
    }else{
        Log.i(TAG, "root folder already exists.");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to implement runtime permission handling in android 6.0 as `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is considered as dangerous permission. Go through : https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: I have implemented runtime permission.

Comment: show your code how you received runtime permissions.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @CommonsWare code sample updated. I also had implementation of the runtime permissions in place alongside this code.